# Mysql time difference UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)

Tags: mysql

My current sql statement is like follows..

```
SELECT * FROM `Main`
WHERE username = '$username'
AND fromsite = '$website'
ORDER BY `votes`.`timestamp` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

however the timestamp column shows a timestamp like " "2014-03-19 12:00:43" ...Following another question I had an answer along the lines of using ...

`SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) AS seconds_ago`

However not great with mysql and still don't see how I can still use the original select statement and work in a function like above, so that converts the timestamp column and shows as seconds ago instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ditch the `*` and list the columns and expressions you want returned.

```
SELECT m.username
     , m.fromsite
     , m.timestamp
     , UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m.timestamp) AS seconds_ago
     , m.votes
  FROM `Main` m
 WHERE m.username = '$username'
   AND m.fromsite = '$website'
 ORDER BY m.votes, m.timestamp DESC
 LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: damn wish it was that obvious before I asked heh.

Comment: If you absolutely have to use the `*`, then qualify it with the table name or alias... `SELECT m.*, UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m.timestamp) AS seconds_ago`